# Get Max Count Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
  SELECT YEAR(BL.[Issued]) AS Year, 
         BL.[Category] as Category, 
         COUNT(BL.[Licence No#]) as LicenceIssued 
    FROM [dbo].[businesslicences$] BL 
   WHERE BL.[Category] = 'PERSONAL SERVICES SETTINGS' 
     AND YEAR(BL.[Issued]) > 2015
GROUP BY BL.[Category], 
         YEAR(BL.[Issued])
ORDER BY COUNT(BL.[Licence No#]) DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

I want to get the maximum value. `LIMIT 1` is not working

Comment: LIMIT is not for MS SQL Server. Add `OFFSET 0 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` instead, which is ANSI SQL and supported by MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

instead of limit use top for sql server:

```
SELECT top 1  YEAR(BL.[Issued]) AS Year, BL.[Category] as Category, COUNT(BL.[Licence No#]) as LicenceIssued 
from [dbo].[businesslicences$] BL 
WHERE BL.[Category]='PERSONAL SERVICES SETTINGS' AND YEAR(BL.[Issued])>2015
GROUP BY BL.[Category], YEAR(BL.[Issued])
ORDER BY COUNT(BL.[Licence No#]) DESC
```